# Memory use if multiprocessing queue is not used by two separate processes

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, multiprocessing

I have a thread in my python program that acquires images from a webcam and puts them in a multiprocessing queue. A separate process then takes these images from the queue and does some processing. However, if I try to empty the queue from the image acquisition (producer) thread I do not free any memory, and the program eventually uses all the available memory and crashes the machine (Python 3.6.6 / Ubuntu 18.04 64bit / Linux 4.15.0-43-generic)

I have a simple working example that reproduces the problem.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import numpy as np

queue_mp = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=500)

def producer(q):
    while True:
        # Generate object to put in queue
        dummy_in = np.ones((1000,1000))

        # If the queue is full, get the oldest object (FIFO),
        # to make space for the latest incoming object.
        if q.full():
            __ = q.get()
        q.put(dummy_in)


def consumer(q):
    while True:
        # Get object from queue
        dummy_out = q.get()

        # Do some processing on the object, which we simulate here by time.sleep
        time.sleep(3)

producer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=producer,
                                           args=(queue_mp,),
                                           daemon=False)

consumer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=consumer,
                                           args=(queue_mp,),
                                           daemon=False)

# Start producer and consumer processes
producer_process.start()
consumer_process.start()
```

I can rewrite my code to avoid this problem, but I'd like to understand what is happening. Is there a general rule that producers and consumers of a multiprocessing queue **must** be running in separate processes?

If anyone understands why this happens, or what exactly is happening behind the scenes of multiprocessing queues that would explain this memory behavior I would appreciate it. The docs did not go into a lot of detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was happening, so I'll post it here for the benefit of anyone that stumbles across question.

My memory problem resulted from a **numpy** [bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12793) in numpy version 1.16.0. Reverting to numpy version 1.13.3 resolved the problem.

To answer the basic question: No, there is no need to worry which thread/process is doing the consuming (`get`) and which thread/process is doing the producing (`put`) for multiprocessing queues. There is nothing special about multiprocessing queues with respect to garbage collection. As [kindall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416467/kindall) explains in response to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729249/does-python-garbage-collect-at-the-end-of-an-iteration-in-a-loop):

> When there are no longer any references to an object, the memory it occupies is freed immediately and can be reused by other Python objects

I hope that helps someone. In any case, the numpy bug should be resolved in the 1.16.1 release.